# What is the difference between dataset name property and dataset instance name?

Tags: c#, ado.net, dataset

I'm reading now about DataSet class, and I know a lot about other essentials in C#, but I didn't see before that there are both, the instance name itself and name property that is initialized through constructor (DataSetName).

```
DataSet ds= new DataSet();
```

and in this case the default DataSet name is set to NewDataSet.

What that property do more than the instance name?

Answer (score 1):

The `DataSetName` property is required to ensure that the XML representation of the `DataSet` always has a name for the document element, which is the highest level element in a schema definition.

You can read about the constructor and `DataSetName` parameter here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7se64052.aspx

You can read about the `DataSetName` property here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.datasetname.aspx